# Is there callback function on speed up transaction in metamask?

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

I developing Dapp using Metamask there is a functionality a Speed Up transaction is an attempt to overwrite a currently pending transaction with a new transaction. in this case scenario, I am unable to get a new transaction hash at the time of executing the contract.

So there is any callback function(or any other way to get new transaction hash on speed up from Metamask ) on speed up I can replace older transactions hash with new transaction hash into my Dapp.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, any wallets including MetaMask do not expose such APIs at the moment.

You have raised a good point though. I think where this feature request should be discussed in web3.js community.

Meantime, I suggest you set your own gas price and gas limit for the transactions before passing them to MetaMask to avoid user facing issues.

Comment: Filed an issue here https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3585